# Why is paintComponent() run even though no one calls it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I was wondering if someone could explain how/why paintComponent() is called right after all the statements in main() are run. The reason I am confused is that there is no explicit call to painComponent() but it is run regardless.

```
// JComponent is a base class for custom components 
public class SimpleDraw extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDraw canvas = new SimpleDraw();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("SimpleDraw"); // jframe is the app window
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 400); // window size
        f.setContentPane(canvas); // add canvas to jframe
        f.setVisible(true); // show the window
    }
    // custom graphics drawing 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; // cast to get 2D drawing methods
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,  // antialiasing look nicer
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(32)); // 32 pixel thick stroke
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE); // make it blue
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());  // draw line 
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.drawLine(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());  
    }
}
```

Comment: The base class calls it.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for your comment, although i can't see any explicit call to it from the base class... is this call implicit? Any further explanation will be useful.

Comment: Because this is how painting works. Swing employees a passive painting approach, only performing a paint cycle when it thinks it needs to be done (as opposed to an active approach, which paints the screen at regular intervals).  Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a decent little write-up](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/15who-calls-paintcomponent.html) on how paintComponent is handled.

Excerpt:

> Who calls paintComponent
>
> ... This method is called because the user did
>   something with the user interface that required redrawing, or your
>   code has explicitly requested that it be redrawn. Called automatically
>   when it becomes visible When a window becomes visible (uncovered or
>   deminimized) or is resized, the "system" automatically calls the
>   paintComponent() method for all areas of the screen that have to be
>   redrawn. Called indirectly from a user-defined listener via repaint() ...

There's more in the write-up as well as some reference links, which, unfortunatelly, are all broken.

I also found [this blog post](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2008/07/controlling-javas-graphics.html) which discusses painting/drawing in Java from a very basic point of view. Check out the first paragraph:

> Why do we put all our graphical drawing code into a paintComponent()
>   method? It seems odd, since it would seem we should be able to simply
>   stick some simple graphics commands into our main() method in a Java
>   application and just get the drawing done. Where does paintComponent
>   come from? If we never call it in our code, how does it get executed?

In the Java docs you actually have to read up on [paint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) to start getting an idea of what going on. The [paintComponent documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) is not very helpful.